# eliminate duplicates and retrieve max(id0 for each eff_date partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns `eff_date`,`name`,`id`,`balance`

| eff_date | name | id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | one | 200,000 |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | tow | 180,000 |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | three | 200,000 |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | four | 180,000 |
| 1402/01/02 | بلند مدت | five | 150,000 |
| 1402/01/02 | بلند مدت | six | 180,000 |
| 1402/01/03 | وام | seven | 200,000 |
| 1402/01/03 | وام | eight | 280,000 |

`id` is auto increment but we have 2 records for each partition of `eff_date`. In the table duplicates occur in rows 3 & 4 so I want in final table `tbl_qry` to eliminate row 1,2 otherwise `max(id)` in each partition of `eff_date` when we have a duplicate, then insert just row 3,4,5,6,7,8.

Like this:

| eff_date | name | id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | three | 200,000 |
| 1402/01/01 | کوتاه مدت | four | 180,000 |
| 1402/01/02 | بلند مدت | five | 150,000 |
| 1402/01/02 | بلند مدت | six | 180,000 |
| 1402/01/03 | وام | seven | 200,000 |
| 1402/01/03 | وام | eight | 280,000 |

I want to write a procedure. What is the best idea for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `group by` and `Max()`

```
select eff_date, name , max(id) as id,  balance
from mytable
group by eff_date, name,  balance
```

Answer (score 0):

(Date format is `YYYY/MM/DD`).

---

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test order by eff_date, id;

EFF_DATE   N         ID    BALANCE
---------- - ---------- ----------
1402/01/01 a          1        200
1402/01/01 a          2        180
1402/01/01 a          3        200
1402/01/01 a          4        180
1402/01/02 b          5        150
1402/01/02 b          6        180
1402/01/03 c          7        200
1402/01/03 c          8        280

8 rows selected.
```

(I presume that ID isn't really *word* representation of a digit, i.e. not "one" but `1`, as you said that it autoincrements. Even it if it, the following query remains the same).

Remove duplicates:

```
SQL> delete from test a
  2  where a.rowid < (select max(b.rowid)
  3                   from test b
  4                   where b.eff_date = a.eff_date
  5                     and b.name = a.name
  6                     and b.balance = a.balance
  7                  );

2 rows deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test order by eff_date, id;

EFF_DATE   N         ID    BALANCE
---------- - ---------- ----------
1402/01/01 a          3        200
1402/01/01 a          4        180
1402/01/02 b          5        150
1402/01/02 b          6        180
1402/01/03 c          7        200
1402/01/03 c          8        280

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```